# Converting to an extended class

Tags: class

Imagine I have a class like so:

```
public class MyClass {
    public string MyString { get;set; }
}
```

And then I extend this like so:

```
public class MyExtender : MyClass {
    public string MyString2 { get;set; }
}
```

How can I convert a MyClass into the extended one, I tried:

```
item = (MyExtender)classitem;
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In the end instead of finding a way to convert it I found a way to copy all the properties to the extended class instead:

```
MyClass orig = GetItem(x);
MyExtender copy = new MyExtender();
PropertyInfo[] infos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo info in infos)
{
    info.SetValue(copy, info.GetValue(orig, null), null);
}
```